# DataFrame query returns UndefinedVariableError: name 'Clasification_1' is not defined

Tags: database, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

this is my code:

```
actionDf = ActionViewDF.query("AC_ActionType==Clasification_1")
```

This code returns:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'Clasification_1' is not defined
```

while in ActionViewDF there is some rows with 'Clasification_1' at 'AC_ActionType' column.

I can't find out what is the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
actionDf = ActionViewDF.query("AC_ActionType == 'Clasification_1' ")
```

Notice the single quote added around `Classification_1`